# Problems using bitmaps for thumbnails

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, user-interface, thumbnails

I'm trying to make an app that takes videos and then displays the videos in a gridview. I have gotten to the point where all the video thumbnails are showing up in the gridview like they should. However, my problem is that the method I am using has a lot of lag time. It takes some time to get the gridview loaded and when I try to scroll there is always some sort of lag. This is most likely due to the fact that I'm using bit maps for every video thumbnail.

I was wondering what I could do to make this a lot quicker and smoother. My code is posted below.

```
class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context; 
ArrayList<String> videopathlist;
Bitmap bmthumb;


VideoAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> filepathlist){
    context = c;
    videopathlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.videopathlist.addAll(filepathlist);
    Log.i(TAG, "" + videopathlist);
}

@Override 
public int getCount() {
    return videopathlist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return videopathlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int posiiton, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
     bmthumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videopathlist.get(posiiton), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
     if (bmthumb != null) {
         Log.i(TAG1, "There is a thumbnail");
         imageview.setImageBitmap(bmthumb);
     } else {
         Log.i(TAG1, "There is NOT a thumbnail");
     }
     imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
     imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 160));


    return imageview;
}
```

Thanks for your  help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

Use a ViewHolder to cache everything, as described here: [Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) (applies to GridViews too)

Also, use an ImageLoader to load images dynamically. There are many available or you can build your own. Here are some:

- [Volley](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138)
- [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [ImageLoader](http://androidimageloader.com/)

All these loaders make use of Bitmap caches as described here: [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Also, you could potentially be actually creating the thumbnail bitmaps when returning the view. This strikes me as very expensive. I would do this as a seperate step, unrelated to displaying them. For example, kick off an `AsyncTask` when your activity is first created to generate any new thumbnails. Then in your adapter just query the `MediaStore` to get the generated thumbnails.