# Errors with FileOutputstream and FileInputStream

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have a `FileOutputstream` here:

```
    public void SaveImage(Bitmap default_b) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("file", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I get an error on this line:

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("file", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

Saying that openFileOutput is undefined *(please note that this is in a base adapter class, and when I try to do it from context, `Context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput` gets the error that "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from type Context") I also get the warning that Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE is deprecated.

Then I have my FileInputstream here (in another class that extends BaseAdapter):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(mContextGV);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new openFileInput("file");
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bitMapA = new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bitMapA);
        Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
        view.setImageBitmap(bM);
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}
```

That has an error on this line:

```
FileInputStream in = new openFileInput("file");
```

saying that openFileInput is undefined and once again when I change it to:

```
FileInputStream in = new Context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("file");
```

I get an error saying that "Context.getApplicationContext() cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: You need to pass in your activity context to your adapter and use that. As a side note you really shouldn't have your view adapter open files as this will be a huge performance hit.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was able to fix the error with the FOS by using `FileOutputStream out = mContext.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("file", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);`but I still get the error on the FIS and I made sure that I had this `private Context Context;` at the top of the adapter

Comment: And also, what do you recommend that I do so that I don't have my view adapter open files?

Comment: Just declaring `private Context context;` doesn't mean anything, it'll be `null`. You need to pass an actual context (a reference to the calling activity, for example) and use that. There are libraries that do image caching and loading in lists and largely solve this problem for you. Take a look at my previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16859222/833647

Answer (score 0):

Try to Replace File OutputStream Code

```
String fname = "Image-" + n ;
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists()) file.delete();
try {
   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
      + "/" + fname +".png");
FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream(f);
default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,fos);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

its works perfect For me to Save Image

Comment: Ok, so when I go to read the file with FileInputStream, I would openFile(f)?